# Application Insights QuickPulse (live metrics stream) not showing up

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app, hosted in IIS, behind a corporate proxy. I've already configured the HttpClient's default proxy in startup.cs, so I'm receiving request telemetry and so on. The problem is, the live metrics stream isn't working - my server doesn't show up. I've also configured the system proxy (via inetcpl.cpl) and it still doesn't work. Any ideas on what else I could try?

Comment: Did you add nuget Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web?

Comment: Does that apply to .NET Core web apps as well? The dependencies on the package lists .NET Framework only.

Comment: Does it work without a proxy?